# Why doesn't this function update the variable properly?

Tags: python, function, addition

Basically, once this code is ran, the program prints 20, 20; whereas, what I would like for it to do is to add a further 20 to the previous gold. So the program should print 20, 40.

```
gold = 0

def display():
    calculate(gold)
    calculate(gold)

def calculate(gold):
    gold += 10
    gold = gold + 10
    print(gold)

display()
```

Comment: just did, sorry about that

Comment: If you want calculate to operate on the global variable gold, why do you need a parameter?

Comment: Your program actually *prints* 20 on two lines. It *returns* `None`

Comment: Where do I return gold?

Comment: You don't. `print` is not the same as `return`

Comment: @ProMCKingz, ints are immutable so any changes in the function don't affect the gold you have defined outside the function.  If gold was a mutable structure like a list and you mutated it in the function it would be reflected outside the function as you would be mutating the original object not creating a new one as you do with  gold +=, if you use `gold = [0]` and do `gold[0] += 10` in the function and print gold outside you will see `gold[0]` is 10

Comment: @Cunningham, thanks alot. I think java uses mutable ints, or I may be wrong, however I did believe that they were mutable.Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were aiming for this:

```
gold = 0

def display():
    calculate()
    calculate()

def calculate():
    global gold
    gold += 10
    gold = gold + 10
    print(gold)

display()
```

Since `gold` is a global variable here, you don't need to explicitly pass it in as a parameter to `calculate`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you call `calculate()`, you are passing in the current *value* of the variable `gold`, not the variable itself.

So when you add 10 to `gold` within `calculate`, the original `gold` variable is unaffected. The two variables have the same name, but point to different values. Below, I have named one of them `gold2` to clarify this point.

If you return the new value from `calculate`, you can update the outer `gold` variable (i.e. rebind the name `gold` to a new int object):

```
gold = 0

def calculate(gold2):
    gold2 = gold2 + 10
    return gold2

gold = calculate(gold)  # 10
gold = calculate(gold)  # 20
```

Comment: don't I have to define gold2?

Comment: @ProMCKingz it's a function argument, so when you pass a value to that function when calling it, it's assigned there.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

```
gold = 0

def display():
    global gold
    gold = calculate(gold)
    calculate(gold)

def calculate(gold):
    gold += 10
    gold = gold + 10
    print(gold)
    return gold

display()
```